# Amazon RDS Oracle DB snapshot restore in different account

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, snapshot

Want to restore DB Snapshot of Oracle from one account(prd) to another account(non-prd) in same region. Could you please suggest the ways how can i achieve the DB restore for oracle in RDS?

whether i can store the DB snapshot in Amazon S3 and try to restore it or is there any alternate method to try it?

I have seen samples for storing the SQL snapshot in S3 and restoring it but whether its possible for oracle. And do we need to create profiles/users/tablespaces in rds oracle before importing the data or it will be taken care of when we restoring it from S3.

Answer (score 1):

The flow would be:

- [Create a DB snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html) of the Amazon RDS database in the Production account
- [Share the DB snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ShareSnapshot.html) with the non-Production account
- [Restore the DB snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html) in the non-Production account to create a new Amazon RDS database

All these operations are managed by Amazon RDS. There is no need to create tables or use Amazon S3. The new database will contain exactly the same data as the source database.

Comment: If i restore the data (from snapshot) into non-production DB instance then it will contain the same data but i want to alter the schema name and modify accordingly to non-production. For eg: in on-prem , we will import the data with different schema name in non-prd DB and give roles and permissions to the new schema and run a post script which will modify according to our non-prd environment. In aws , i want to import the data with different schema name and have to attach the lambda funtions for password rotaion.

Comment: That is not possible if you use an Amazon RDS "DB snapshot". So, one option is to restore it as suggested above, and then modify the restored database. Or, you can use some other way to dump and restore the data, but that would be up to you to manage rather than using a method provided by Amazon RDS.